# How to set Swagger with GAE+Jersey+Maven?

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, jersey, swagger

How can i set Swagger (to document APIs) with GAE+Jersey+Maven?

I've included dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

and in web.xml:

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.my.webservice.config.ServiceConfig</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
        <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

where ServiceConfig class is:

```
    public class ServiceConfig extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(UserResource.class);
        s.add(ImageResource.class);
        s.add(GsonMessageBodyHandler.class);

        return s;
    }
}
```